# Running script on server prevents local copy & paste

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I have a powershell script running on a server which performs some copy and paste commands with files.

While the script runs, if I copy something on my local machine it doesnt not copy; the script copy commands is overwriting my local buffer. I suspect this is happening because I'm logged into the server and have the clipboard integration enabled, is there anyway I can stop the script interferring with my local clipboard as I thought it would use a server-side clipboard and not mine, just because I'm logged into the server.

I know straight away when my copy stops working that a script has started running on the server. Just hoping to find out if there's a way I can still use clipboard integration with my remote login and separate the clipboards somehow just for the script environments, or at least not make the things its copying overwrite my buffer. Thanks for reading!

Comment: Can you post part of the script where the copy takes place? Without it, its going to be extremely hard to give you an answer.

Comment: Save the script locally on the server and then run invoke-command against it with `-AsJob` parameter if you know running the script locally works as a quick workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Any of these options would work to avoid using your local clipboard:

1. Disable clipboard in your RDP session under Local Resources/Local devices/Clipboard.
2. Replace `Get/Set-Clipboard` commands in your script with simple variables.
3. Have your script disconnect your rdp session (but keep it running) before setting clipboard:

```
tsdiscon.exe (Get-Process -PID $pid).SessionID
```

4. If your script is running via scheduled task, set the task to run "whether user is logged on or not". This forces powershell to run in another session.
5. If you start the script manually, use remote powershell instead of your RDP session:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "MyServer" -ScriptBlock {C:\path\to\script.ps1}
```

---

But if you cannot do any of those options, you *could* try to reduce the impact by setting your current clipboard to a variable, running your script, then setting your clipboard back to what it was, like:

```
# save current clipboard:
$clip = Get-Clipboard

# do stuff
Set-Clipboard "myText"
Get-Clipboard | Out-File stuff.txt

# set clipboard back:
Set-Clipboard $clip
```

This only works for text though. If you copy an object like a file to your clipboard, then it will just get overwritten.